# Discord Welcome Bot (Python) Not Working Even Though There Is No Error

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a discord bot in python that will send a simple welcome message when someone joins the server. I looked into a number of youtube tutorials and tried many different ways to make it work but for some reason it is not working.

There is no error in the code. I have an `on_message(message)` function in my code just to test the bot and that function works perfectly.

On the other hand, the `on_member_join` function is the one that is not working. I have the member intents function enabled on my discord developer portal and the bot has admin permissions. I tried sending the message as an intent and it still doesn't work.

Edit 1 : As per the comments I have deleted the second definition of client. Still cant get the bot to show the welcome message. The `on_message(message)` works.

Edit 2: I solved the error. The error was due to me overwriting the definition of client and also due to a typo. Thanks to everyone that helped!

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

token = "I have my token here"


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
client = discord.Client(intents = intents)



@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")


#respond hello to hi (for testing if the bot works)
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == 'hi':
        await message.channel.send('Hello')



#main function
@client.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    guild = client.get_guild(I have my server ID here)                        #server id
    channel = guild.get_channel(I have my channel ID here)                     #channel id
    await channel.send(f'Welcome to the server {member.mention}!  ')     #edit this line to edit message



client.run(token)
```

Comment: Why do you defined `client` two times?

Comment: Delete the second definicjom of client, you’re overwriting the first one without any intents

Comment: Made the edit but still doesn't work.

Comment: In the docs it says that "Intents.members" Needs to be enabled, in your code the first letter isn't capitalized (intents.members -> Intents.members), so could that have an effect on it?

Comment: No @Okkonen, he named his discord.Intents instance in lowercase “intents”, so your suggestions is just gonna throw a NameError

Comment: Oh i see nvm then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo in `member.metion`. It should be `member.mention`

Comment: OMG I can't believe that was actually the problem. The surprising thing is that the code gave me no error even though there was a typo. You are a life saver. Can't believe I spent hours trying to find where I went wrong.

Comment: check the answer as accepted so the problem results resolved

Comment: @VishnuVijay That is not any issue. It happens. Even I spend hours on a problem fully awake and solve it when I just woke up.